# Wix ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost and Caliburn Micro

Tags: mvvm, wix, caliburn.micro

I'm using Wix 3.8 for building my installer files. For my boostrapper bundle I want to build my own gui with the ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost. I found an example at: [Custom WiX Managed Bootstrapper Application](http://bryanpjohnston.com/2012/09/28/custom-wix-managed-bootstrapper-application/)

This application is using MvvM Light. How can I use Caliburn Micro and Mef instead? I have tried to build up the standard mef bootstrapper and call:

`new AppBootstrapper();`

in my overridden Run method. But I get a NullReference exception here. How can I manually call the Caliburn Micro Bootstrapper from code?

Regards Markus

Comment: I am trying to do the same, but I am getting a null reference exception when `PrepareApplication` is called which is called by `Initialize`. The intellisense for PrepareApplication is: "Provides an opportunity to hook into the application object." Overriding PrepareApplication to do nothing or creating a new application programmatically (`this.Application = new Application()`) doesn't seem to help either. Did you ever figure this out?